# Declare a public "static" function inside a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, oop, static-methods

Suppose I need to declare some **private** *static* members to use it in some **public** *static* methods...

```
// ***** Variant I *****
function supports() {
    var impl = document.implementation; // private, non-static
    this.SVG = function () {            // public, non-static
      return impl.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1");
    };
}

// ***** Variant II *****
function supports() { }
supports.prototype.impl = document.implementation; // public, non-static
supports.SVG = function () {                       // public, static
  return impl.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1");
};
```

I know there are some difficulties in JavaScript with the 'static' OOP concept, so my question about is:

Can I declare ***public static*** methods **inside** the "declaration body" of the 'object' (like in the "Variant I" above)?

Comment: `supports.prototype.impl = ...` - **public non-static** (member)

Comment: @hindmost: thanks for correction! I fixed the comment accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I see after analyzing some answers is this one:

```
var Person = (function () {

    var _privateStatic = 'private static member';
    function privateStatic() {
        return _privateStatic + ' + private-s-function';
    }

    function Person() {

        this.publicNonStatic = 'public, non-static member';
        this.publicFunction = function () { 
            return this.publicNonStatic + '+ public non-static-function'; 
        }

        var _privateNonStatic = 'private, non-static member';
        function privateNonStatic() {
            return _privateNonStatic + " + private-ns-function"
        }

        this.publicStatic = Person.publicStatic = 'public static member';
        this.publicStaticFunction = Person.publicStaticFunction = function () {
            return Person.publicStatic + ' + public static function';
        }        

        // Accessible internal 
        var test = _privateNonStatic;
        test = _privateStatic;
        test = privateStatic();
        test = privateNonStatic();

        // other class declarations
    }
    return Person;
}());

// Accessible external members: 
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.publicFunction());
console.log(p.publicNonStatic);
console.log(p.publicStatic);
console.log(p.publicStaticFunction());
console.log(Person.publicStatic); 
console.log(Person.publicStaticFunction());
```

PS.

I remarked however that publicStaticFunction() becames accesible only after a `new Person()` declaration... so, **before** it they are **not** available:

```
// Accessible external members: 
console.log(Person.publicStatic);           // NO WAY
console.log(Person.publicStaticFunction()); // NO WAY

var p = new Person(); // lazy declaration 

console.log(Person.publicStatic);           // IS OK!
console.log(Person.publicStaticFunction()); // IS OK!
```

, so I suppose there is no way to achieve it INSIDE the function `Person` body, only inside the anonymous function that wraps the `Person`...

So the initial SVG sample should be like this:

```
var supports = (function(){
    function supports() { this.SVG = supports.SVG; } 
    supports.SVG = function () {
        return document.implementation.hasFeature("http://shortened", "1.1");
    };
    return supports;
}());

// usage of public, static method
if (supports.SVG()) {return 'supports SVG!';}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Variant II the function that is supposedly private and static is neither private nor static.

You are correct that it is quite difficult to define a private static member of the class, but it is possible if you exploit JavaScript's scope.

```
var Person = (function(){

    var privateStaticProperty = true;

    function privateStatic() {
        return privateStaticProperty;
    }

    function Person(){

        // class declarations
    }

    Person.prototype.example = function() {
        return privateStatic();
    }

    return Person;
}());

var p = new Person();
console.log(p.example());
```

Note, however, that if you extend the prototype outside of the closure, the supposedly private static members will not be available.

Comment: how about to declare *public* static methods inside the "class body"?

Comment: @Serge you have figured that out yourself in variant II `supports.SVG` is public and static. Make sure you keep that out of the class declaration (as is in your example), because everything that is inside will be executed each time the class is instantiated, which is also why it is used as a constructor.

Comment: So you confirm that in JavaScript **is impossible** to declare a "public static" function *inside* the 'class declaration', (like in C#, by ex.) it only should be *wrapped* in a anonymous function

Comment: @Serge it is possible, but it will be redefined each time you instantiate the class and that makes no sense. JavaScript does not have an object model like other programming languages like C++, C#, Java etc. Wait until you need a destructor :D It is called a class but it is no class, it is just a function, which is also an object, because functions are objects in JavaScript

Comment: how do you declare a *public static* method inside the Person() function? even if redefined?! to use like `Person.Foo()`

Comment: @Serge just like you have, just move it inside the "class". Again - this makes no sense.

Comment: moving inside the class does not create a static method, because that method will not exist until the first class is created. so is not a static method. I would like to use `Person.Foo` and perhaps never create a `new Person()`...

Comment: @Serge I guess you are correct, so the best you can do is declare it outside.

Comment: perhaps is not "the best", but the only solution... ) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Serge IMHO before [ECMA6 support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) is reliably available you should use JavaScript as a functional language unless you *really* need objects for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

There is no private, static or public in JavaScript. There is only local and global, in-scope and out-of-scope. Use an IIFE to capture a variable and return a closure; this should work equivalently to a static method.

```
var supports = (function supportsWrapper() {
    var impl = document.implementation; // "static"-ish.
    return function supports() {
      this.SVG = function () {
        return impl.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1");
      };
    }
})();
```

`impl` will be initialised only once, and will be readable only by `supports`, but will persist between calls to it.

Comment: how about to declare *public* static methods inside the "class body"?

Comment: There is no "class body" in JS (at least as of ES5). And if you are going by Java's definition of "static method", they're just functions defined on the constructor function. You will be much happier if you stop writing Java in JavaScript, and start writing JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, there is no term or keyword static, but we can put such data directly into function object (like in any other object).

**Static methods**

Static methods, just like variables, are attached to functions. They are used mostly for objects:

```
function Animal(name) {
  arguments.callee.count = ++arguments.callee.count || 1 

  this.name = name
}

Animal.showCount = function() {
  alert( Animal.count )
}

var mouse = new Animal("Mouse")
var elephant = new Animal("elephant")

Animal.showCount()  // 2
```

Comment: Is there a way to declare public static methods *inside* the "class body"?

Comment: `callee` seems to be depreciated : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee